# How to align a image and a text together side by side, using css and react.js

Tags: css, reactjs

[This is what I wanted to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R6oX.png)

[This is what I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owh8S.png)

This is the code that I have right now, I try using inline and all the css syntax I can think of, but it is still not working quite right. I try the margin padding in react. I am also using a box to box up all the components and everything inculding the image and the text.

```
p {
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: -50%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here are some of the code in the react.js file

```
<div className={classes.empty}></div>
        <div className="container">
          <img
            className={classes.img}
            src={ProfilePic}
            alt="Profile"
            style={{ marginTop: "12%", display: "inline-block;" }}
          ></img>
          <p>
            So May See Macy <br />
            Computer Science Major <br />
            Current Standing: Sophomore <br />
            GPA: 3.6
          </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you to split the container with 2 <div>s.

And use `align-items` attribute in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

and remove the inline-block attributes from the `p` and `img` elements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `flexbox`

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justiry-content: start;
    align-itemt: center;
}

.container img, .container p {
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.container img {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.container p {
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: -50%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

[Read Flexbox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center; 
}
```